# PdfCopy breaks the string replacement of PDF using iTextSharp

Tags: itext

I have two pdfs, lets say content and header.
Now I want to add this header to the top of content.

So first, I have used Document, PdfWriter then took the PdfContentByte (canvas) to place the header.pdf inside content with desired location.

This addTemplate method breaks the format of PDF.
I already have string replacement method after this merging, which is not working now after this merge method.

After the suggestions from iText, I tried to use PdfCopy or PdfSmartCopy. 
But **how can we place this header in desired location using PdfCopy ?**

**If not, then how to merge without breaking the format of PDF using writer / pdfContentByte ?**

Note:
I have tried to merge the Pdfs by using PdfCopy, but again its breaking.

`PdfObject pdfObject = dict.GetDirectObject(PdfName.CONTENTS);
(pdfObject is PRStream)`

Here the pdfObject is not a PRStream instead it becomes PdfArray.

**Please help me to resolve this issue.**

Comment: Upgrade to iText 7. You tagged your question as an iText 7 question, but you're using iText 5 or earlier.

Comment: I only have the license of iText5, so I cannot use iText7. 
Is there any other way to resolve this ?

Comment: That you are surprised that the page contents can not only be a stream but alternatively also an array of streams shows that you know very little about PDFs. That you claim this is breaking the pdf format only stresses that. That your string replacement method fails in that case merely shows that that method is utterly broken. Thus, first of all you had better correctly analyse the issue and recognize that your code is broken and start fixing it instead of claiming other software is broken.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but my question was why it is not working in v5 - as I mentioned above that I do not have the v7 license. Plus I did tried out my requirement in the likeness of the example that was mentioned in the documentation of the itext which did not work. Hence asked if there is anyway to achieve this via iText5.